# How to show specific nodes from xml?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I created a code to display data from XML. I need to filter some data from XML and show in the page. Actually I need to show only three nodes in the page. When click the view all button, need to display other nodes. Please help me to implement the code.

Here is the code.

```
function showCD(xml){
    xml = $(xml).children();
    $(xml).children().each(function () {                    
        let TITLE = $(this).find("TITLE").text();
        let ARTIST =$(this).find("ARTIST").text();
        let COUNTRY = $(this).find("COUNTRY").text();
        let COMPANY =$(this).find("COMPANY").text();

        let html = `<div class="col-md-4">
                      <p>${TITLE}</p>
                      <p>${ARTIST}</p>
                      <p>${COUNTRY}</p>
                      <p>${COMPANY}</p>
                    </div>`;

        $("#xmldata").append(html);
    });
}



<div class="row" id="xmldata"></div>

   <section>
                <div class="container">
                    <input type="button" value="View All" id="myButton" class="reveal" onclick="toggler('toggle_container');">

                        <div id="toggle_container" class='hidden'>
                        <div class="block">
                           <div class="row" id="xmldata"></div>
                        </div>
                </div>
             </div>
    </section>
```

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG>
  <CD category="new">
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD category="hide">
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
  </CD>
<CATALOG>
```

It is just like below image.

[image]

http://next.plnkr.co/edit/KgmzSWEaIOBRf54M?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview

Comment: Please add a sample of the XML involved to the question, and include how your current code does not meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code as per your requirement [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/IENfDTeinF7cJCofOqAK)

instead of 2 separate xmldata & xmldataall divs you can use only one div & hide all the children > 2 index.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"test.xml",
        dataType:"xml",
        success:showCD
    });
});

function showCD(xml){
    xml = $(xml).children();
    let i = 0;

    $(xml).children().each(function () {                    
        let TITLE = $(this).find("TITLE").text();
        let ARTIST =$(this).find("ARTIST").text();
        let COUNTRY = $(this).find("COUNTRY").text();
        let COMPANY =$(this).find("COMPANY").text();
        
        let html = `<div class="col-md-4">
                      <p>${TITLE}</p>
                      <p>${ARTIST}</p>
                      <p>${COUNTRY}</p>
                      <p>${COMPANY}</p>
                    </div>`;

        i++;

        if(i <= 3)    {
            $("#xmldata").append(html);
            $("#xmldataall").append(html);
        }
        else{            
            $("#xmldataall").append(html);
        }
        
    });
}

$('#myButton1').click(function () {
                                var self = this;
                                change(self);
                            });

                            function change(el) {
                                if (el.value === "View All")
                                    el.value = "Hide All";
                                else
                                    el.value = "View All";
                            }

                            function toggler(divId) {
                                $("#" + divId).toggleClass("hide");
                                $("#xmldata").toggle();
                            }


                            function directLinkModal(hash) {
                                $(hash).modal('show');
                            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    

</head>
<body>

      <div class="row" id="xmldata"></div>

   <section>
                <div class="container">
                    <input type="button" value="View All" id="myButton1" class="reveal" style="float: right;"  onclick="toggler('toggle_container');">

                        <div id="toggle_container" class='hide'>
                        <div class="block">
                           <div class="row" id="xmldataall"></div>
                        </div>
                </div>
             </div>
            </section>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't view your demo.

Comment: "Oh dear, something didn't go quite right" - Perfect example of why the **answer must contain the code** that supposedly fixes it, instead of linking to something external that may break (or disappear).

Comment: @bhagwanparge, Your answer is perfect. Thanks a lot..!